# Scroll to bottom when dynamically inflating view

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-view, android-scrollview

I have a `LinearLayout` and I'm inflating a `CardView` in it like this:

```
final LinearLayout itineraryDetailLL = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.itineraryDetailLinearlayout);
final View childView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.cardview, null);
itineraryDetailLL.addView(childView);
```

The inflation of the child view is done on a onclick of a button. I want to scroll to the bottom of the screen whenever a new cardview is inflated. I'm doing it like this:

```
ScrollView scrollview = ((ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.masterScrollView));
scrollview.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
```

but this scrolls to somewhere middle of the screen and not to bottom. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you can do this by ''scrollview.smoothScrollTo(0, (int) childView.getY());" after inflating it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to post an event to happen on the next frame, when this `ScrollView` would be laid out:

```
    scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
        }
    });
```